# Find nested Dictionary value based on N number of array items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to solve this problem: I've got an array of values that could or could *not* be keys in a dictionary. I then want to add them if they aren't present.

```
myarr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
mydict = {'one': {'two': {'three': {}}}}

for item in myarr:
   if item in mydict:
      (this is where my brain shuts off)
   else:
      (via some sort of magic)
      mydict[insert_magic_here] = {'four': {}}
```

I've tried auto-incrementing with a `for i in range(len(myarr)):` but that didn't work. I've also tried doing a `mydict = mydict[i]` to dive deeper into the dictionary but that codes me into a corner.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show your expected output. I'd recommend using more descriptive variable names than `myarr` and `mydict`, which tells me basically nothing about what their purposes are.

Comment: Will the nested dictionaries always be in the same order as the keys in `myarr`?

Comment: Show where in `mydict` you expect to add `{'four': {}}` and show the final expected result.

Comment: - keys will always be in the correct sequential order

Comment: Last element will be nestled under the previous element in the same fashion

Answer (score 0):

This is a curious exercise; somewhat analogous to appending elements to a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). The usual solution is to use a `current` variable to keep track of where you currently are in the sequence, and update `current` to be the next "node" on each iteration.

```py
myarr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
mydict = {'one': {'two': {'three': {}}}}

current = mydict

for item in myarr:
    # insert if not present
    if item not in current:
        current[item] = dict()
    # advance to next
    current = current[item]
```

Result:

```
>>> mydict
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': {}}}}}
```

The problem with your original solution may have been that you used `mydict` as the "current" variable meaning you lost the original reference to the main dictionary (the first "node").

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you!